# Javascript closure variable retention

Tags: javascript, memory, closures

I am facing a strange case of closure. In the following code snippet, defaultConfig is maintained as a closure variable even though it has no use left once test has been initialized. To insure that config contains only copies of defaultConfig's members, I have used slice to process its elements, but it still remains in memory, which can be verified by placing a breakpoint inside render. Also, it can't be found in closure if it has not been touched or used at all. I am unable to find any reason. I am using Chrome.

```
function test() {
    "use strict";

    var defaultConfig = ["as", "lx", "ms", "sw"];

    return view;

    function view(config) {
        if (!config) {
            config = [];

            for (var attr in defaultConfig) {
                config.push(defaultConfig[attr].slice(0,1));
            }
        }

        this.render = function() {
            console.log(config);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it has no use ? `test()` returns a function which does use `defaultConfig`.

Comment: Your code can probably be fixed but I don't understand the goal.

Comment: Can you re-word your question to include what your goal is? It sounds like you want your code to work one way but don't know how to achieve that. It sounds like you would like defaultConfig to go out of scope.. but there is still an active reference to it in the returned function. In order to make it go out of scope you would need to have view go out of scope. You can view the retaining chain in the Chrome dev tools.

Comment: The function assigned to *view* has a closure to **all** outer variables (as does the one assigned to *this.view*), whether they are used or not.

Comment: there is no point in defining defaultConfig outside view. you can directly set the array inside view function when config is undefined. Whats the point in keeping closure variable if you wont use it across different instances of the function.

Comment: @RobG: "has a closure to all outer variables" --- they don't count as a references though. So if there is no reference - the variable will be marked as a GC candidate.

Comment: @zerkms— "*they don't count as references though*" sure they do (how can they not? Do you have a spec reference?). Smart compilers might optimise away unused closures (seems pretty sensible to me, given the wide use of closures), but you can't be certain of that unless you know the internal workings of specific implementations.

Comment: @RobG I must have checked ES before my comment. Surprisingly it mentions nothing about GC implementation and references in closures. :-S